# calling 2 Console applications from 1 with only 1 .exe

Tags: c#, .net, console

I have an issue I can't seem to think of a good way to solve.

Basically I have a bunch of console applications. Say A.exe B.exe C.exe ...

Now I would like to do things such that sometimes A and B are both required. Or A and C, etc. Any number of combinations.

I was originally thinking to Create a Solution named AandB, then Include project A and project B. Is this the best way to go about this? I basically still need A and B to be seperate, but some clients will need A and B together. I want it to remain modular.

Comment: What's wrong with "calling 2 Console applications from 1 with only 1 .exe"?

Comment: Why don't you have just one solution and have A, B, C ... as projects included in it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to seperate out the logic of the applications A,B and C. These should be seperate class structures or projects. The three "host" command line applications called A,B and C can include all the application logic inside them using project references.